# How to implement excel-like formula editor in XtraGrid?

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I'm working on complicated system, which allows some values in grid to be calculated by formulas.
Right now I have textbox control above grid.
It works in this way:
When you start editing inside in-place editor and first symbol is '=' - focus is moved to that textbox control above. 
At this moment grid is made readonly, and when user clicks on grid cells - coordinates of the clicked cell are passed to formula editor, so it can add links to formula. When you press Enter or Esc in text editor - formula is being written to underlying dataset and grid is made editable back.

The goal:

I want this too look more like Excel grid. Don't like focus to jump somewhere outside.
Is it possible to keep editor open and at the same time allow user to click anywhere on grid? So, all formula editing will be performed inside inplace editor?
Right now, there's no event to disallow closing editor. If I use 'ValidateEditor' event - it doesn't even allow to use scrollbars.
Is there a way to keep editor open and leave navigation working?

Answer (score 0):

---

Seems I have found way round that myself. 
I handle ValidatingEditorEvent, and if edit value starts with '=' I set boolean flag in my control. Also, I remember text before and after cursor position, and cell coordinates (FocusedRowHandle, FocusedColumn).
When I receive Click event, I get clicked cell coordinates and if boolean flag is set - I focus previous cell, activate editor and add what I need to inpalce editor.
Seems to work fine.